# What is the easiest way to send a signal from one stream deck to a stream deck on a different computer?

Tags: notifications, webserver, streamdeck

I want to use Elgato stream decks (or similar devices) in my company. Let's say user A presses a green button on his stream deck, and the same button should turn red on all stream decks in the company. User B presses the corresponding (now red) button on his stream deck and the button turns green again on all stream decks.
What is the easiest way to achieve this behaviour? I have a webserver available to store the status of the button and receive requests.

It will be easy to send a GET request to the webserver to announce that the button should be red now, but how do the other stream decks get a notification?